# Не меняется шрифт в VS CODE

Tags: json, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Не меняется шрифт в VS Code. Пытаюсь поменять на Terminus Bold, но он не изменяется. Пробывал другие, тоже не работает
OS: Manjaro Linux
Файл settings.json: https://pastebin.com/03YzAB2W

Comment: Vs code (как и хром) не умеет битмапные шрифты которым является терминус

Comment: Где-то был терминус, переделанный в векторный ttf, попробуйте его.

Comment: Спасибо, @HolyBlackCat, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Vs code не умеет битмапные шрифты которым является терминус.
Нужно скачать TTF шрифт Terminus. Вот ссылка: https://files.ax86.net/terminus-ttf/